# How to create NSRange object in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: xcode, applescript, nsrange, applescript-objc

I can't create NSRange object in ASOC. I've googled it but with no luck.

I have tried: 
`current application's  NSMakeRange_({0, 1})`
`current application's  NSMakeRange_({location:0, length:1})`
`current application's  NSRange's NSMakeRange_({location:0,length:1})`

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too complicated:

```
set range1 to current application's NSMakeRange(0, 1)
```

And – since C structs can be represented by AppleScript lists or records – still easier:

```
set range2 to {location:0, |length|:1}
```

AppleScriptObjC recognizes the "literal" creation as `NSRange`